# Is Initializing state with props object causes mutation?

Tags: reactjs, mutation

In my React application, one of the components needs state initialization from props.

```
Class ComponentA extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      objectA: props.objectA
    }

    }

    someOnclickFunction(e){
      let updatedObjA = this.state.objectA;
       updatedObjA.value = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
         objectA: updatedObjA
       })
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, `props.objectA` reference is copied to state. So, Am I mutating the `props` indirectly by updating the state?
Or `setState()` function will clone the object and keep new reference for the `objectA`?

Answer (score 3):

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // state is null at this point, so you can't do the below.
        // this.state.objectA = props.objectA

        // instead, initialize the state like this:
        this.state = {
            objectA: props.objectA,
        };

    }

    someOnclickFunction(e) {
        // you can't set "objectA.value" like the following
        // this.setState({
        //     objectA.value: e.target.value
        // });

        // you need to create a new object with your property changed, like this:
        this.setState({
            objectA: Object.assign({}, this.state.objectA, { value: e.target.value }),
        })
    }
}
```

This is a mistake that many beginners at react make. You can't simply update sub-properties of an object without consequences.. The following would also be wrong:

```
someOnclickFunction(e) {
    var tmp = this.state.objectA;

    // WRONG: don't do this either, you're modifying the state by doing this.
    tmp.value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        objectA: tmp,
    });
}
```

To elaborate on the correct way to do this using `Object.assign`.. this function takes all the parameters and merges them into the first element. So by providing a new object as the first parameter, you've created a copy of your first object with your new property.

```
Object.assign({}) // = {} 
Object.assign({}, objectA) // = copy of objectA
Object.assign({}, objectA, { value: "newValue" }) // = copy of objectA with 'value' = 'newValue'.
```

Note: `Object.assign()` is a shallow clone, not a deep clone.